# Spring MVC- Authentication with or without salt

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

My current method of registering and authenticating a User is as follows:

```
class User{

private String username;
private String password;
private String salt;
}
```

Registeration :

```
addUser(String username, String password){

user.setUsername(username);

user.setSalt(BCrypt.gensalt());

user.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(password, user.getSalt()));
}
```

Authentication :

```
authenticate(User user){

User userDB = getUserFromDB(user.getUsername());

userDB.getPassword().equals(BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), userDB.getSalt()))

}
```

However I am looking at Spring Boot authentication systems and I see people recommending using **BCryptPasswordEncoder** which only uses password and no salt.

I needed to know if my existing method is better or worse than the one being recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` uses a salt. From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.CharSequence-):

> ```
> public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword)
> ```
>
> Encode the raw password. Generally, a good encoding algorithm applies a SHA-1 or greater hash combined with an 8-byte or greater randomly generated salt.

From the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java):

```
public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
    String salt;
    if (strength > 0) {
        if (random != null) {
            salt = BCrypt.gensalt(strength, random);
        }
        else {
            salt = BCrypt.gensalt(strength);
        }
    }
    else {
        salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
    }
    return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), salt);
}
```

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` generates its own salt upon encoding. This is what the optional `SecureRandom` constructor argument is used for. The output of BCrypt includes the salt, which is how a raw password is verified. This is why the `matches` method requires the already encoded password.

Sample output from bcrypt "example":

```
$2y$10$Tqq.bRDh6N3JDNzn0oBd7OCFjsHyiuf39VMmZnrw9MWi.xtTiWtni
```

The output of bcrypt includes:

- `2y` indicates Blowfish cipher
- `10` rounds (actually 2^10 rounds)
- first 22 characters after third `$` are the salt, remainder are the hash

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) describes bcrypt output:

> Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".

---

Your method does the same thing, but you are storing the salt explicitly by itself. Instead of storing the salt separately, you can simply use the salt that is stored in the bcrypt output, as described in the method [`public static boolean checkpw(String plaintext, String hashed)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html#checkpw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I doubt `BCryptPasswordEncoder` does use salts. Neither `encode` nor `matches` provide mechanisms to pass salts as parameters to the methods. Also, the doc from this method is [copied from the interface's method description](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.CharSequence-) and is just an advice.

Comment: Storing the bcrypt output is sufficient. You do not need to store salt separately. See additional edit.

Comment: actually, 2y - suggested new marker for the fixed crypt_blowfish.
more details at: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes