# How BCryptPasswordEncoder works in Spring.Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm trying to understand how spring security can match the raw password entered by user with the encoded password in the database in the case of random `password salting` by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

My questions: AFSK `bcrypt(random salt + password) = random encoded password`, so since bcrypt is a `one-way hashing function` and the encoded password is fixed in the database, I guess spring security will somehow get the `salt` while encoding password and before check matches using `BCryptPasswordEncoder：boolean matches(java.lang.CharSequence rawPassword, java.lang.String encodedPassword)`, right?

If so, where the `salt` is stored, in the database or somewhere else?

If salt is in the database, how to defend against cracking if the database is exposed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471731/spring-mvc-authentication-with-or-without-salt

Answer (score 0):

The salt is stored in the same column as the hashed password. Salts are not considered to be secret. Since each is unique it prevents  pre-calculating rainbow tables.

If you want higher security, consider peppering (password stays in application and HMACs the salted hashes)